# Is this a correct syntax to check if specific variable is set and display on the website?

Tags: php

This below is just a line of my script, but I wanted to ask if it's good in terms of syntax?
I've cut it off from the rest of the function and it's used to display `login_time` grabbing data from the table and checking if it's `offline` to display `N/A` and else display the actual info .. so please let me know. I am asking about the basics such as if `'offline'` is set correctly or it should be with `""` and this kind of stuff. Will be greatly appreciated.
Oh, and also to remove `()` from `($data['Status'] == 'offline')` or not?

```
    .....................
$replace = array
(
            'total_time'    => $data['Status'] == offline ? $this->secondsToTime(intval($data['TotalTime'])) : $this->secondsToTime(intval($data['TotalTime']) + (time() + 10800) - intval($data['LoginDT'])),
            'login_time'    => $data['Status'] == offline ? "N/A" : $this->secondsToTimeCurr(time() + 10800 - intval($data['LoginDT'])));
    .....................
```

Comment: This is more a question of style than it is correctness.  As such, it will be difficult to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is messy , dont do it inside of the array:

```
$replace['login_time'] = ($data['Status'] == 'offline') ? 
                         "N/A" : $this->secondsToTimeCurr(time() + 10800);
```

---

Ternary is good, but it is meant to be short, if it is hard to read, use regular if statement.

```
if($data['Status'] == 'offline'){
   $replace['login_time'] = "N/A";
}else{
   $replace['login_time'] = $this->secondsToTimeCurr(time() + 10800);
}
```

---

Another approach is to use more variable

```
$isOffline = $data['Status'] == 'offline';
$secondsToTimeCurr = $this->secondsToTimeCurr(time() + 10800);
$replace['login_time'] = $isOffline ? "N/A" : $secondsToTimeCurr;
```

---

There are more ways to write the same code the most important is that is readable.

As for the single quotes, it makes the string verbatim.

For the parenthesis again it is just for readability.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Llama which part did I miss, may be I can expand further

Comment: Oops, I removed my previous comment.  OP's question seems to be more about style (single quote vs double quote, paren usage, etc) than it is about actual code correctness.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I elaborated more in my answer to address all questions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand it's messy but however is it correct even when it's messy? I prefer to be all in the array since I've got a lot of similiar variables and otherwise it will be messy for me. I've updated my main post with my updated arrays. Please let me know if it seems okay?

Comment: If it is working then it is okay @Monk25, like I said in my answer as long as it is readable than you are fine. if it takes more lines to be more clear then do that

Comment: @Monk25 in other word your syntax is correct, if you can make it easier to read than do it. this is called refactoring.

Comment: I understand, so it's all good. Just last question if possible: do you think this maybe really overloading to the server where it's running? I mean I've got a ranking where it display top 100 users. so imagine if like 50 are online, and if 10-20 people load the page to check the rankings, in that case it will do a lot of calculaction .. my question is: can `$this->secondsToTime(intval($data['TotalTime']) + (time() + 10800) - intval($data['LoginDT']))` somehow overload the server or it shouldn't at all even if its displaying a lot of users as ranking and calculating for each separately?

Comment: have you notice any performance issue ? if so add benchmarks to see where you can optimize your code, otherwise I would not worry because computer nowadays are so fast, 10-20 people is not a large number you know ?

Comment: I cannot test it in production enviroment at this moment. So, to sum it up. `Overall as you said, it shouldn't be a concern(?) since it's basic calculation but still if it calculate for like 100 users at a time, do you believe this could be an issue based on the lines I updated in my main post?` It's substracting and adding values on another value + `time()`

Comment: Yes that is fine @Monk25 but if you find yourself repeating the same calculation store it into a variable to reuse its value, dont recalculate for better performance

Comment: @Monk25 did I answeer your question or do I need to elaborate

Comment: Just do you think that it can overload the server by accessing the script from more people and doing these calculations? it's highly unlikely as I think but let me know please?

Comment: I see that you are worry about performance which is good. There could be many factors in this. But you mention you got about `100` users, that is not a big deal. Server Hardware is also important.If you notice a lag or a slow down then you need to start optimizing. but only if this affects performance otherwise  you should not worry about it. This is called [Micro-optimisation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding)

Comment: See also this [blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) it explain why it shouldnt matter

Comment: I can tell you this, you can spend your time being productive at other things instead of worrying about how few calculation would affect performaance